# How to access the function itself in apply-like functions

Tags: r, functional-programming, apply

I want to do an apply / map function-like but using one element of the list as a operand of the calling function.

I give you better an example, let's say I want to subtract to every element of a list, the first element of the list, i.e.: `x[i] = x[i] - x[1]`.

If I understood correctly, when calling the function with apply, the function gets the current element of the list, x[i], only as an argument, but I would need the list itself to access to the first element (x[1]) and subtract it to the current element (x[i]).

I would expect a way to provide to the applying function an extra argument or access to the list itself.

Comment: With frames and lists, you can do `lapply(x, \`-\`, x[[1]])`; with arrays/matrices, `apply(mtx, 1, \`-\`, mtx[,1])`. Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` can take multiple arguments.

Consider list `lst`,

```
> lst
$X1
[1] 1 2 3

$X2
[1] 4 5 6

$X3
[1] 7 8 9

$X4
[1] 10 11 12
```

and first as `h`ot element.

```
> h <- 1
```

Then we provide `lst` without that element as first argument to iterate over, and `lst[[h]]` as second argument after the function. In contrast to `Map` the latter will always passed as a whole.

```
> lapply(lst[-h], \(x, y) x - y, l[[h]])
$X2
[1] 3 3 3

$X3
[1] 6 6 6

$X4
[1] 9 9 9
```

If you aim to replace all but the hot element, do

```
> lst[-h] <- lapply(lst[-h], \(x, d) x - d[[h]], lst)
> lst
$X1
[1] 1 2 3

$X2
[1] 3 3 3

$X3
[1] 6 6 6

$X4
[1] 9 9 9
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(lst)
list(X1 = 1:3, X2 = 4:6, X3 = 7:9, X4 = 10:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Base R functions

Of course in this case you could just do `v[1] - v` but I think the question is more general. One way is to supply an argument from the global environment.

```r
v <- 1:10
lapply(v, \(x) v[1] - x)
# ^^ produces list of integers from 0 to -9
```

However, I think you're right that it's generally better to pass the arguments that a function is using to it directly. One way to do so is to use [`Map()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) which,

> applies a function to the corresponding elements of given vectors.

```r
Map(`-`, v[1], v) # Also returns a list
```

You could also use `mapply()` though this will simplify the output by default in a similar way to `sapply()`, in this case to an `integer` vector. The output format can change if the input changes.

```r
mapply(`-`, v[1], v) # [1] 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9
# Or to return a list
mapply(`-`, v[1], v, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Another base R function that you can use with two arguments is `outer()`, which returns a `matrix`:

```r
outer(v[1], v, `-`)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7   -8    -9
```

#### Specifying the output type

The [`purrr::map2()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) family are,

> variants of map() that iterate over two arguments at a time.

These allow control over the output class in a similar fashion to `vapply()`:

```r
purrr::map2(v[1], v, `-`) # returns a list
purrr::map2_int(v[1], v, `-`) # returns an integer vector
purrr::map2_dbl(v[1], v, `-`) # returns a numeric vector
purrr::map2_chr(v[1], v, `-`) # coerces to character vector with warning
purrr::map2_lgl(v[1], v, `-`) # returns an error - cannot coerce integer to logical
```